# cos function in sass return undefiend operation error

Tags: css, sass

```
@if ($nav-position == "bottom-right") {
    @if ($n == "first") {
      transform: translate(-$r, 0);
    } @else if ($n == "last") {
      transform: translate(0, -$r);
    } @else {
      transform: translate(floor(-$r * cos($theta)), floor(-$r * sin($theta)));
    }
  }
```

This won't work, what is the reason? I've tried to compile it using terminal or GUI cilent, both gave me the same error:

[image: error]

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: What is  `$theta`? Impossible to see the error here, share a complete example, not only a piece

Comment: @deceze http://i.imgur.com/AiUdq0j.png

Comment: Can you copy and paste that as text into your question?!

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude someone got a same issue https://github.com/callmenick/CSS-Circle-Menu/issues/2

Comment: @deceze I can't it's error msg given my compass.app, which is not selectable at all.

Comment: There are no `cos()` or `sin()` functions in SASS. Either you have to write these functions yourself, or find some other way to do what you want to do. A list of all the available SASS functions are listed here: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html

Comment: This site has an example of creating the trigonometric functions in SASS: https://unindented.org/articles/trigonometry-in-sass/&num=1&client=firefox-b-ab&hl=en&gl=uk&strip=1&vwsrc=0

Answer (score 0):

i think you are passing the values in a wrong order, i tried reproduce that error.

Paste this code on [SassMeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/) to an easy check

**SASS CODE**

```
@mixin transform($r, $theta, $n: 'first' ,$nav-position: 'bottom-right' ) {
  @if ($nav-position == 'bottom-right') {
    @if ($n == 'first') {
      transform: translate(- $r, 0);
    } 
    @else if ($n == 'last') {
      transform: translate(0, - $r);
    } 
    @else {
      transform: translate(floor(-$r * cos($theta)), floor(-$r * sin($theta)));
    }
  }
}


// First IF 'bottom-right' TRUE

  // IF

h1 {
  @include transform(5, 1)
}  

 // ELSE IF  'FIRST' 
h2 {
  @include transform(5, 1, 'first')
}

 // ELSE IF  'LAST' 
h3 {
  @include transform(5, 1, 'last')
}

 // ELSE
h4 {
  @include transform(5, 1, 'else')
}

 // NOTHING IS PRINTED
h5 {
  @include transform(5, 1, 'else', 'yeka')
}

 // ERROR APPEARS WHEN YOU PASS THE PARAM IN A WRONG ORDER
 // UNCOMMENT TO CHECK IT

 /*

h6 {
  @include transform('144px', 5, 1)
} */
```

**CSS OUTPUT**

```
h1 {
  transform: translate(-5, 0);
}

h2 {
  transform: translate(-5, 0);
}

h3 {
  transform: translate(0, -5);
}

h4 {
  transform: translate(-3, -5);
}
```

**CSS ERROR when H6 rule is uncommented**

```
Undefined operation: "-"144px" times 0.28366".
```

As you can see i created a mixin with the 4 parameters

```
$r
$theta
$n
$nav-position
```

and the 2 last have a default value for easy maintain,
everything works as expected but in the last example ( the commented one for the h6 heading ) 
When you uncomment you see then your error. I was trying to pass the '144px' value as the first param but should be the third one. So everything crash since **$r** and **$theta** *have to be a NUMBER but instead got a string*

If the problem is with the ELSE case, then the problem is the units, [use unitless function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#unitless-instance_method) for the $theta and $r values before cos or sin function is executed.
But then you have to be ensure that you're passing the same units, px and px, not px and rem for example.
Or you can create and nest another function to check these cases